# Can't open contents of internal laptop HDD via enclosure and I tried to format it using Tails OS but failed

Tags: linux, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, enclosures, tails

I bought a new hard disk enclosure today for my internal drive. I connected it to my laptop using the connection, and everything was working fine. I was able to access all the files stored in it, but when I tried to access the Users folder under the OS partition in it,  it prompted `you need administrator permission to access the folder` and there were Continue and Cancel options. I clicked Continue, then suddenly my file explorer stopped responding and everything froze.

I tried to eject it but the eject option was not coming, so I directly pulled out the hard disk enclosure without ejecting. And then I tried to reconnect it again. And it keeps on loading and I'm not able to access anything in it. I tried restarting my system, and I also tried connecting to other laptop, but I still have the same issue.

Then somebody suggested me to check in Linux so I live booted Tails OS and tried to connect it, but it was not accessible under normal file manager, there is disk utility in tails OS where it showed my enclosure hard disk and it showed as 1TB free so I thought the data was gone and tried to format it but got this error (check below in the screenshot). Now every time I connect it to Windows computer it runs on 100% usage at all times and the diskpart, chkdsk utilities freeze if I try to use them.

I don't want the data in it any more, but I want this drive to work.

Error message after formatting in Linux:

[image]

Magnified image:

[image: magnified image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i just want the hard disk to work. i am not able to access  it + i am not able to format it.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, when you make a new installed drive, you get new userids.  These cannot access other users' private data.  Accessing as Administrator on Windows should work.  As Administrator, you can also grant access for other users.  I can't explain the "freeze".

On Linux, what you tried to do was create a new partition.  Since all the space was used, you couldn't do it.

What you probably want to do on Linux is to **mount** the existing filesystems.

Comment: I tried accessing as Administrator after that but did not work.

Comment: i feel like after i tried to format it in Linux  it got worse and maybe corrupted. is there  anyway i can format it and make it usable again? . (i dont care about data in it)

Comment: If you really REALLY **REALLY** don't care about the data...  delete the existing partitions.  Then make a new one (or ones) and format.  This should be doable with either OS.

Comment: I really really dont care about data in it. i tried 'diskpart' utility in windows to format it, but once i connect the enclosure the utility does not go any further. can you tell me a better way to format  it?

Comment: First off... forget "format" for a minute.  There are three levels: a low level format you haven't been able to do to a hard disk this century;  partitioning, which according to your pictures you have six of;  filesystem creation, which puts a filesystem into one partition.   'diskpart' should be able to create and delete partitions.  I don't know it specifically, but look for a "delete" option, possibly in a context menu.  Alternatively, the tool you were using in Linux should be able to do it too.  (again, look for "delete").  Don't forget to save.  Windows should offer to setup thereafter.

Comment: i tried to format using 'disk management' in windows. but the utility crashes once i connect my enclosure. even third party software such as easeus, crystaldiskinfo, ext2fsd crashes.

Comment: Crashing tools may indicate a corrupt filesystem or partitioning.  Try the linux ones.

Comment: thank you for your answer David G., good explanation.  i will try on linux. can you suggest me some utilities or application in linux which i can use to fix my harddisk issues?

Comment: I prefer the command line tools for the most part.  I would start with `gdisk`, or now maybe `fdisk`.  Both should recognize and be able to repair or replace damaged partitions.   Either way, be very careful to get the CORRECT disk.  These tools are perfectly willing to wipe out any disk.  But even the one you pictured should work.

Comment: thanks will try and let u know.